# Adjusting icon size /tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, size, resize

How can I make these icons have identical size?

[image]

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/twenty-seconds-curriculum-vitae/kfgsngtymkfj

The code that adds the rounded backgrounds is below. Can I modify it somehow to get what I need?

```
\newcommand*\icon[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt, fill=mainblue,mainblue,text=white] (char) {#1};}}
```

Then the list with icons is printed here:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm} @{\hskip 0.5cm}p{5cm}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvdate}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Info}} & \givencvdate\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvaddress}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Letter}} & \givencvaddress\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givennumberphone}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Telefon}} & \givennumberphone\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Mundus}} & \href{\givencvsite}{\textcolor{cerulean}\givencvsite}\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvmail}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{@}} & \href{mailto:\givencvmail}{\givencvmail}}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you have to modify the `cls` file. I actually don't know whether it looks right in your context, since you do not provide a complete document showing your settings.

First, change the definition of `\icon` to

```
\newcommand*\icon[2][-1.3mm]{\tikz[baseline={(0,-1.5mm)}]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt, fill=mainblue,mainblue,text=white,minimum width=6.5mm] (char) {\makebox[0pt][c]{\raisebox{#1}[0pt][0pt]{#2}}};}}
```

Modify `6.5mm` for the size of the blue discs and `-1.5mm` to shift the discs up and down relative to the line.

I have added an optional argument to `\icon`, for vertical adjustment of the icon within the disc. I used it twice, so you have to change the following lines as well.

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvdate}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon[-2mm]{\Info}} & \givencvdate\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvaddress}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Letter}} & \givencvaddress\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givennumberphone}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Telefon}} & \givennumberphone\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Mundus}} & \href{\givencvsite}{\textcolor{cerulean}\givencvsite}\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvmail}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon[-1mm]{@}} & \href{mailto:\givencvmail}{\givencvmail}}
```

Finally, you should change the string that the style uses for identification (first line of the `cls` file):

```
\ProvidesClass{twentysecondcv}[2021/08/02 CV class patched]
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works much better than my walkaround.

I only changed icon[2][-1.3mm] to icon[2][-1.5mm], since it made the image off-center in some cases, and skipped the second part entirely, as it was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a walkaround!
"Large" and "large" are not the same!

I changed all to small "l" and it lined the icons up.

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvdate}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Info}}
```

to

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvdate}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{\Info}}
```